# Mapping a composite foreign key to a composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems mapping composite keys in jpa / hibernate. The parent entity and the child entity both have composite primary keys.

I have been able to use @mapsId when the parent entity has a simple key and the child has a composite key.

In the hibernate documentation they use @JoinCoumns in the mapping to demonstrate mapping two composite keys. But in their example its not clear where those column references are defined.

I have the following:

```
@Embeddable
public class PriceRequestLegKey implements Serializable {
   @Column(name = "leg_request_id")
   private String requestId;
   @Column(name = "display_index")
   private int displayIndex;
   ...
}

@Embeddable
public class AllocationKey implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "leg_request_id")
   private String requestId;
   @Column(name = "display_index")
   private int displayIndex;
   @Column(name = "allocation_index")
   private int allocationIndex;
   ...
}

@Entity(name = "PriceRequestLeg")
public class PriceRequestLegModel {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PriceRequestLegKey legKey;
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "leg_request_id", referencedColumnName = "leg_request_id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "display_index", referencedColumnName = "display_index")
   })
   private List<AllocationModel> allocations;
   ...
}

@Entity(name = "Allocation")
public class AllocationModel {

   @EmbeddedId
   private AllocationKey allocationKey;
   @ManyToOne
   @MapsId
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "leg_request_id", referencedColumnName = "leg_request_id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "display_index", referencedColumnName = "display_index")
   })
   private PriceRequestLegModel leg;
   ...
}
```

At runtime when saving it gives the follow exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.lbg.legato.rfq.data.entity.AllocationKey.displayIndex; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.lbg.legato.rfq.data.entity.AllocationKey.displayIndex
```

Which I assume is spurious as there are getters and setters. I also get the same error if I use mappedBy="leg" on the priceRequestLegModel and @MapsId on the AllocationModel. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restore the `mappedBy="leg"` to the `PriceRequestLegModel` `@OneToMany` annotation:

```
@Entity(name = "PriceRequestLeg")
public class PriceRequestLegModel {

   @EmbeddedId
   private PriceRequestLegKey legKey;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="leg", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<AllocationModel> allocations;
   ...
}
```

Then you should change `AllocationKey` to reference `PriceRequestLegKey`:

```
@Embeddable
public class AllocationKey implements Serializable {

   PriceRequestLegKey legKey; // corresponds to PK type of PriceRequestLegModel
   @Column(name = "allocation_index")
   private int allocationIndex;
   ...
}
```

And then set the value of the `Allocation.leg` `@MapsId` annotation appropriately:

```
@Entity(name = "Allocation")
public class AllocationModel {

   @EmbeddedId
   private AllocationKey allocationKey;
   @ManyToOne
   @MapsId("legKey")
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "leg_request_id", referencedColumnName = "leg_request_id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "display_index", referencedColumnName = "display_index")
   })
   private PriceRequestLegModel leg;
   ...
}
```

Some examples like this are in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) section 2.4.1.

Comment: Brian, thank you very much. Changing the AllocationKey to reference the PriceRequestLegKey solved it. Much appreciated.